# Form Recognizer Custom model returning error during the prediction and the error code is 3014

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I have trained multiple custom models and using those custom models into the following piece of code.

```
Response<RecognizedFormCollection> forms = await client.StartRecognizeCustomFormsFromUri(modelId, invoiceUri).WaitForCompletionAsync();
```

the very first custom model I trained is still working fine. rest of the are not working. Here's the error I am getting.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> RequestFailedException: Generic error during prediction. Status: 200
> (OK) ErrorCode: 3014
>
> Additional Information: error-0: 3014: Generic error during
> prediction.
>
> Content:
>
> Headers: ms-azure-ai-errorcode: REDACTED
> x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 27 apim-request-id:
> 476f6fbf-b833-413a-8b04-84c7959d1334 Strict-Transport-Security:
> max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload X-Content-Type-Options:
> nosniff Date: Wed, 17 Mar 2021 02:05:37 GMT Content-Length: 213
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> Azure.RequestFailedException: Generic error during prediction. Status:
> 200 (OK) ErrorCode: 3014
>
> Additional Information: error-0: 3014: Generic error during
> prediction.
>
> Content:
>
> Headers: ms-azure-ai-errorcode: REDACTED
> x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 27 apim-request-id:
> 476f6fbf-b833-413a-8b04-84c7959d1334 Strict-Transport-Security:
> max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload X-Content-Type-Options:
> nosniff Date: Wed, 17 Mar 2021 02:05:37 GMT Content-Length: 213
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> at
> Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.Models.RecognizeCustomFormsOperation.UpdateStatusAsync(Boolean
> async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.Models.RecognizeCustomFormsOperation.UpdateStatusAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) at
> Azure.Core.OperationHelpers.DefaultWaitForCompletionAsync[TResult](Operation`1 operation, TimeSpan pollingInterval, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.OperationExtensions.WaitForCompletionAsync(Task`1
> operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> OCR.Controllers.FormRecognizerController.Index(FormModel frmFile) in
> C:\Users\nmuidil\source\repos\OCR\OCR\Controllers\FormRecognizerController.cs:line
> 115 at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
> mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
> arguments) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g_Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.gAwaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
> context) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.gAwaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.gAwaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> context) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.gAwaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.gAwaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g_AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you training with the new API 2.1-preview.3 and analyzing with an older versions of the API. If yes, can you please also analyze using the same new release API 2.1-preview.3 new models are not available in previous API versions. Old models are available in new API version for backwards compatibility.
If this is not the issue can you please reach out to Form Recognizer Contact Us formrecog_contact@microsoft.com or open a support ticket and please include the Model ID.

Comment: Thank you very much @Neta for the valuable answer. somehow my code is pointing to v2.0. But the nugget I installed is Azure.AI.FormRecognizer(3.1.0-beta.2) which is suppose to point v2.1.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I am using SDK 3.1.0-beta.3, but there is no information which API it is targeting (unlike the documentation of SDK 3.0.0 says it targets API 2.0). I have built the model with v2.1 preview 3. Since I am using the latest SDK and it still does not work, does it mean we need to wait for another version of SDK to use the latest API preview?

Comment: The current SDK does not yet support 2.1-preview.3 API, a new updated SDK is planned for early April that will support the new API. Until then please use the REST API for the latest preview release - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/client-library?tabs=preview%2Cv2-1&pivots=programming-language-rest-api